# How to apply filters to *ngFor Roles in Angular7

Tags: angular

Current, I am developing a Web Application Project for School using Angular-7 as the frontend. I display the User Role on checkboxes whereby you can select more than one Role.
I have the following User Roles

1. Teacher, 2. Student, 3. Parent, 4. Admin, 5. SuperAdmin

RolesCheckService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TokenService } from './token.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RolesCheckService {

  isAdmin = false;
  isStudent = false;
  isTeacher = false;
  isParent = false;
  isSuperAdmin = false;

  constructor(private token : TokenService) {
    if(this.token.checkRole('Admin')) {
      this.isAdmin = true;
    }
    if(this.token.checkRole('Student')) {
      this.isStudent = true;
    }
    if(this.token.checkRole('Teacher')) {
      this.isTeacher = true;
    }
    if(this.token.checkRole('Parent')) {
      this.isParent = true;
    }
    if(this.token.checkRole('SuperAdmin')) {
      this.isSuperAdmin = true;
    }
  }
}
```

user.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ApiService } from '../../../shared/services/api.service';
import { SnotifyService } from 'ng-snotify';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { TokenService } from '../../../shared/services/token.service';
import { RolesCheckService } from 'src/app/shared/services/roles-check.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.scss']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

users = null;     //Store Users Data
roles = null;     //Store all roles Data
clients = null;

public error = {
  'role' : null,
  'email' : null,
  'client_id' : null,
  'first_name' : null,
  'last_name' : null,
  'password' : null
};

role = null;
User = 'User';

data = {          //User Update Data
 "id" : null,
 "first_name" : null,
 "last_name" : null,
 "client_id" : null,
 "role" : []
}

form = {         //New User add Data
  'first_name' : null,
  'last_name' : null,
  'email' : null,
  'client_id' : null,
  'password' : null,
  'password_confirmation' : null,
  'role' : []
}

headers = {     //Token for API Authorization
  'Authorization' : this.token.get(),
  'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest'
}

isSuperAdmin = false;

constructor(private roleManage : RolesCheckService , private route : ActivatedRoute, private pg:   NgbPaginationConfig, private token : TokenService, private http : HttpClient, private router :   Router,private api : ApiService, private notify : SnotifyService) {
 pg.boundaryLinks = true;
 pg.rotate = true;
}

ngOnInit() {
  console.log('isSuperAdmin: ' + this.roleManage.isSuperAdmin);
  this.isSuperAdmin = this.roleManage.isSuperAdmin;
  if(!this.isSuperAdmin){
    this.notify.error("Permission Denied");
    this.router.navigateByUrl("/home");
  }
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    if(params['role']){
      this.role = params['role'];
      this.User = this.role;

  } else {
    this.User = 'User';
    this.role = '';
  }
})
this.notify.clear();
this.notify.info("Loading...", {timeout: 0});

if(this.keyword) {
  this.api.get('users?search=' + this.keyword + '&page=' + this.pagination.page + '&sort=' + this.sortData.col + '&order=' + this.sortData.order + '&role=' + this.role, this.headers).subscribe(
    data => this.datahandler(data),
    error => { this.notify.clear(); console.log(error); this.notify.error(error.error.message); }
  );
} else {
  this.api.get('users?page=' + this.pagination.page + '&sort=' + this.sortData.col + '&order=' + this.sortData.order + '&role=' + this.role, this.headers).subscribe(
    data => this.datahandler(data),
    error => { console.log(error); this.notify.error(error.error.message); }
  );
}
this.api.get('role', this.headers).subscribe(
  data => { console.log(data); this.roles=data; },
  error => { console.log(error); this.notify.clear(); this.notify.error(error.error.message); }
);
this.api.get('users/clientall', this.headers).subscribe(
  data => this.clients = data,
  error => { this.notify.error(error.error.message) }
);
}


datahandler(data){
 console.log(data.data);
 this.notify.clear();
 this.users = data.data;
 this.pagination.max = data.total;
}

//New User add Handling
add(){
  this.notify.clear();
  this.form.first_name = null;
  this.form.last_name = null;
  this.form.email = null;
  this.form.password = null;
  this.form.password_confirmation = null;
  this.form.role = [];

  var modal = document.getElementById('addModal');
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

checkboxAdd(event){
  if(event.srcElement.checked){
  this.form.role.push(event.srcElement.name);
} else {
  var index =this.form.role.indexOf(event.srcElement.name);
  this.form.role.splice(index, index+1);
}
  console.log(this.form.role);
}

addModalSubmit(){
  this.notify.clear();
  this.notify.info("Wait...", {timeout: 0});
  this.api.post('users', this.form, this.headers).subscribe(
    data => {
      this.notify.clear();
      this.notify.info("User Added Successfully", {timeout: 2000});
      this.ngOnInit();
      this.closeAddModal();
   },
     error => { this.notify.clear(); this.error = error.error.errors; }
  );
 }

closeAddModal(){
 this.error = {
  'role' : null,
  'email' : null,
  'client_id' : null,
  'first_name' : null,
  'last_name' : null,
  'password' : null
};
  var modal = document.getElementById('addModal');
  modal.style.display = "none";
 }
}
```

user.component.html

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <a (click)='add()' class="btn btn-block btn-success" style="margin-right: 15px;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New {{ User }}</a>
</div>
   <div id="addModal" class="modal" style="background-color: rgb(0,0,0); background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Add New {{ User }}</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" (click)='closeAddModal()'>
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form #editUserForm=ngForm>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">First Name</label>
                <input type="name" name="first_name" id="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" [(ngModel)]="form.first_name" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name">Last Name</label>
                  <input type="name" name="last_name" id="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" [(ngModel)]="form.last_name" required>
                </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name">Email</label>
                  <input type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="example@email.com" required [(ngModel)]="form.email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Role</label>
                    <div *ngFor="let role of roles">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="{{ role.name }}" value="{{ role.name }}" (change)="checkboxAdd($event)"> {{ role.name }}
                    </div>
                </div>
          </form>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)='addModalSubmit()' [disabled]="!editUserForm.valid">Save changes</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)='closeAddModal()'>Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to alter the code from here,

```
<div *ngFor="let role of roles">
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{ role.name }}" value="{{ role.name }}" (change)="checkboxAdd($event)"> {{ role.name }}
  </div>
```

1. If logged-in user is Teacher, the Roles to be displayed should be: Teachers and Students
2. If Logged-in user is Admin, it should display all Roles
3. If logged-in user is Student, it should display: Student

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You need filter in roles. Bases on users.name this roles.filter( role => { if (user.name === teacher) { return role.name === ' teacher' | | role.name === 'student' }});

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to filter roles list right after you receive them from the backend. So you have to change the following code:

```
ngOnInit {
  // ...
  this.api.get('role', this.headers).subscribe(
    data => { console.log(data); this.roles=data; },
    error => { 
      console.log(error); this.notify.clear(); 
      this.notify.error(error.error.message);
    }
  );
  // ...
}
```

You need to add some filter function, where you assign `data` to `this.rules`.

Something like:

```
ngOnInit {
  // ...
  this.api.get('role', this.headers).subscribe(
    data => { console.log(data); this.roles=this.filterFn(data); },
    error => { 
      console.log(error); this.notify.clear(); 
      this.notify.error(error.error.message);
    }
  );
  // ...
}

filterFn(rolesList) { // returns filtered roles list
  // detect what roles should be applied.
}
```

How to detect. I don't see whole your code, but I think `RolesCheckService` can do this work, so you can use it.

You also can go rxjs way. You can define some observable like `appliedRoles$`.

The code would be:

```
roles$ = new Subject();
appliedRoles$ = roles$
  .pipe(
    map(this.filterFn) // map operator have to be imported as `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
  );

ngOnInit {
  // ...
  this.api.get('role', this.headers).subscribe(
    data => { this.roles$.next(data); },
    error => { /** **/ }
  );
  // ...
}
```

And you will use it in html like:

```
<!-- -->
<div *ngFor="let role of appliedRoles$ | async">
  <input type="checkbox" name="{{ role.name }}" value="{{ role.name }}" (change)="checkboxAdd($event)"> {{ role.name }}
</div>
<!-- -->
```

Don't forget to add `CommonModule` to imports block of a module of your component. [`AsyncPipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe#ngmodule) is a part of `CommonModule` from `@angular/common`.

You also can avoid using of AsyncPipe. You have to put applied roles to some variable like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  // don't forget to unsubscribe (!!!)
  this.appliedRoles$.subscribe(appliedRoles => {
    this.appliedRoles = appliedRoles;
    // if you will use ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush strategy, you have to do `markForCheck` there (it is a method of ChangeDetectorRef)
  });
}
```

Don't forget to use new variable `appliedRoles` in the html of your component.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve what you want is to create directive for roles.
Also in you RolesCheckService you should create private subject of current role and public observable of that subject. So in your directive you subscribe to the observable of the role. You put all your logic in your directive.

In the directive you can access the current role and check if it matches the user role.

Here is the guide of [similar directive you want to achieve](https://medium.com/@eliasmsedano/angular-4-how-to-check-authorization-based-on-role-and-entity-states-cf0282280961).

Once you write your directive lets say you call it *canAccess. you just add it to your input in ngFor.

```
<div *ngFor="let role of roles">
    <input *canAcess="role.name" type="checkbox" name="{{ role.name }}" value="{{ role.name }}" (change)="checkboxAdd($event)"> {{ role.name }}
  </div>
```

this will pass the role name in the directive.

Hope this helps! check the guide for more info.